# upgrading default python version or install another python version in Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-3.x, upgrade

I want to upgrade python's default version i.e `/usr/bin/python` in Linux.

I have multiple python versions installed as

```
/usr/bin/python2.7   
/usr/bin/python3.3
```

However, `python` command still returns `python2.7`

```
# python
Python 2.7 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Now, I have installed a module, which got installed in the default version `2.7`.

That's why I can't use `python3.3 script.py`, as it returns error for missing module.

How to update this default version to `3.3`?

Is there a way to install the module in `/usr/bin/python3.3` as well?

**Added:** Module is `pexpect-2.3`.

Comment: What version of Linux are you using? The only distribution that symlinks python to python3 is Arch AFAIK.

Comment: How did you install the module? `python3.3 setup.py install` should do the right thing, if you installed from source.

Comment: @Wooble `python3.3 setup.py install` It is failing with errors. Module is `pexpect-2.3`.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain - `RHEL 6.3 x86_64`

Comment: "Pexpect was written and tested with Python 2.5. It should work on earlier versions that have the pty module." would make me think there's no way it's going to run on Python 3.

Comment: @Wooble Ya I think so. I might have to go with different module in that case.

Comment: [pexpect-u](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect-u) looks like a fork that does work on python 3; haven't tried it myself.

Comment: @Wooble. pexpect-u solved problem for python3.3 and worked great. Also now I know how to change default python so both ways are great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing new `python`, installs by default in `/usr/local/bin`.

Adding this path to PATH before previous default python's path, solves the problem.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
# This export statement could be added to .bashrc for permanent effect.
```

This way old python is not messed and new one is installed.

Also, If there is already a `python` present in `/usr/local/bin`, changing symbolic link of `/usr/local/bin/python` to new `/usr/local/bin/python3.3` solves the problem. (Python install generally only creates link when it installs in /usr/local/bin. You can do `ls` on /usr/local/bin/python to verify that it is link. Because python is installed as /usr/local/bin/python2.7 and then a link to this is created as below)

> /usr/local/bin/python -> /usr/local/bin/python2.7
>
> or
>
> /usr/local/bin/python -> /usr/local/bin/python3.3

Ofcourse, path of this should be added to PATH as already mentioned above.

It's always better to never touch and mess with `/usr/bin/python` version, unless there is strong reason, because /usr/bin/python is generally not a link and is required by many of os modules.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is good though, however I have found another hack trick to this problem and I think it's pretty simple.

At the location of `/usr/bin/` there are many python related files available. You can see the file `python` is actually a link and it points to the `python2`(which is pointed to `python2.7`).
So whenever you command ***python*** it calls the `python2.7` not `python3.5`

The solution is to delete the original `python` link and make another link that points to `python3.5` and make the newly link file name to `python`.

And you are done.  :D

Comment: Note that there is a reason why those distribution use python2 as reference for the `python` executable: some programs are still not python3 ready. While (e.g.) Ubuntu is putting a hardwork moving towards python3, it still has to update quite some of its components which means that doing what you describe *will* currently break a lot of your system. Hopefully in one or two years the major distributions will move to python3 only, but until then I don't think this is a good idea. Just specify `python3` when launching your programs!