# Upgradation to Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-19.04

I have Ubuntu 19.04 OS and I needed python 3.6 version so I somehow managed to get python3.6 on my device without removing python3.7 but now I would like to revert back to using python3.7. Can anyone suggest how to do it?

Comment: "Somehow"? I suppose those details are important. Also it sounds more like a question for AskUbuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [upgrading default python version or install another python version in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957836/upgrading-default-python-version-or-install-another-python-version-in-linux)

Comment: There is a similar question here: [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957836/upgrading-default-python-version-or-install-another-python-version-in-linux)

Answer (score 1):

If you've got multiple version of Python installed, you can choose which one to use as default in `update-alternatives`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

, then follow the prompt instructions.

Comment: update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python3
I am getting this

Comment: Run this in a terminal: `which python3.6`. Does it return anything?

Comment: It returns this ```/usr/local/bin/python3.6```

Comment: And `which python3.7`?

Comment: The same ```/usr/bin/python3.7```

Comment: Try this then: `sudo update-alternatives --config python` (without '3' at the end).

Comment: Had already tried that. Got this ```update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python3```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210244/discussion-between-subhang-v-and-0buz).

Answer (score 1):

Try using virtual environments, namely anaconda for these kinds of things. I am not aware of any other methods. Anaconda basically creates a virtual environment in which you can specify the version of all packages including python itself